# How to combine aws_subnet.prod_subnet.*.id with aws_subnet.prod2_subnet.*.id into a single list

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to combine all subnets to be able to attach an ACL to them.

I have two subnets that exist which different resource names, so it's forcing me to have two ACL blocks which I don't want.

Right now the ACL subnet_id blocks for both ACL blocks read as:

```
resource "aws_network_acl" "prod_public" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.prod.id
  subnet_ids = aws_subnet.prod_public.*.id
}

resource "aws_network_acl" "prod2_public" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.prod.id
  subnet_ids = aws_subnet.prod2_public.*.id
}
```

this works, but I'm want something that will create a list of BOTH set of subnet_ids so I can just have be one block.

I've tried something like this, but didn't work.

```
resource "aws_network_acl" "prods_public" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc_prod_id
  subnet_ids = [aws_subnet.prod_public.*.id, aws_subnet.prod2_public.*.id]
}
```

I also tried using tostring and toset which didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [concat](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/concat):

```
subnet_ids = concat(aws_subnet.prod_public.*.id, aws_subnet.prod2_public.*.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Because neither of these resources is using the `count` argument, the splat operator `*` is redundant here and it would be sufficient to just refer to the single object for each resource:

```
resource "aws_network_acl" "prods_public" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc_prod_id
  subnet_ids = [
    aws_subnet.prod_public.id,
    aws_subnet.prod2_public.id,
  ]
}
```

Using the legacy splat operator `.*` (or its modern equivalent `[*]`) makes Terraform convert each single object into a one-element list containing that object, and so in your example you created a list of lists of strings rather than just a list of strings.

If you *were* using `count` for these resources then their values would then actually be lists, and so in that case it would be appropriate to use the splat operator to select just the `id` attribute of each one but you'd then need to use a function to combine the multiple lists together. Because `subnet_ids` expects a *set* of subnet ID strings (the subnets have no meaningful order), the clearest way to represent that would be using the `setunion` function, which will produce a set of strings containing all of the distinct elements across all of the given lists:

```
resource "aws_network_acl" "prods_public" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc_prod_id
  subnet_ids = setunion(
    aws_subnet.prod_public[*].id,
    aws_subnet.prod2_public[*].id,
  )
}
```

Using the `concat` function would also work, but ultimately Terraform will convert its result into a set of strings to pass into `subnet_ids` anyway and so using `concat` might be misleading to a future reader who might assume that means that the ordering of the subnet IDs is somehow significant.